# Meteor, Mongo insert field value via function issue

Tags: mongodb, meteor, insert

I'm new to Mongo, so maybe this is silly Q, but I cant find similar problem online. When I try insert document with a field value calculated in function, field simply is not in object. Result is something like this

```
var token = function(){
  return "xxxyyy";
}

var companyId = Companies.insert({
 name: company.name,
 email: company.email,
 country: company.country,
 city: company.city,
 token: function(){
        return token();
        }
});

Result is this document:
{
    "_id" : "fm36vAH58787fJq66",
    "name" : "TestCo",
    "email" : "email@email.com",
    "country" : "",
    "city" : ""

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really want a function in your JSON or only the result? If you want the result, try this:

```
var token = function(){
  return "xxxyyy";
}

var companyId = Companies.insert({
 name: company.name,
 email: company.email,
 country: company.country,
 city: company.city,
 token: token()
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But I did not realize that my problem lies in variable token. In my project it is in global scope. When it is declared localy it works like in your example. Thank you.